# Installing RethinkDB on a 32 Bit Architecture

Tags: nosql, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit, key-value-store, rethinkdb

Does [RethinkDB](http://RethinkDB.com) not offer 32 bit versions?

[RethinkDB's download page](http://www.rethinkdb.com/download/) has download links to various *nix packages, but all of them pertain to 64 bit architectures.

Is there a 32 bit version or is it simply not supported?

Comment: Okay, a little patience led me here,

http://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/#prerequisites

Seems they only support 64 bit architectures, there wasn't any explicit information about this in their downloads page. Kudos for politely conveying the fact, RethinkDB!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** We've just added 32-bit support in RethinkDB 1.3, see how to install it at [rethinkdb.com/docs/install](http://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/install).

*Original answer*:

> RethinkDB is currently only available for 64-bit architectures. We may offer 32-bit support in future versions of RethinkDB.
>
> I'll be sure to pass a note along to make the download page clearer about prerequisites.

Comment: Thanks for your response Mr.Glukhovsky.

Comment: Just updated my answer as we've added 32-bit support in RethinkDB 1.3.